# Insert output of schemer to Terminator config

Tags: bash, automation, terminator

My problem consists mainly of ignorance towards the different linux commands. I've run into a wall as I'm at a loss of words to correctly look up the commands I need.

However, I'd like to take the string that schemer (github.com/thefryscorer/schemer" outputs and insert it into my Terminator config at the line which starts with "palette=", replacing the existing info.

The purpose is to set this to run at intervals to keep my cycling wallpaper list updated with my bash colors.

If you could point me towards a place to learn of such automation and usage of commands, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two things you'll need are `sed` and `cron`.

`sed` is a stream editor.  In particular, it uses regular expressions to allow you to search through text files and replace parts of your text.

In particular, if you have

```
#conf.config
palette=REPLACE_ME
other.var=numbers
```

You can say `sed s/REPLACE_ME/replaced_text/g conf.config`

And sed will replace the text in conf.config with that second argument ("replace text").

So that'll be in a bash script you write.

What you'll want to do then in regularly execute your script, which you do by setting up a `cron` job.  This will regularly execute a file.

You can either put your shell script in any one of the /etc/cron folders `etc/cron.hourly`, `etc/cron.daily`, etc, **or**

enter `crontab -e` at the terminal to open your personal cron configuration file, for more fine-grained control over when your commands execute.

The format of a cron command is as follows:

`minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week command`

So you could execute a command (as is explained in the sources below) once a week on Monday afternoon with

`30 17 * * 1 /path/to/command` (30=min, 17=5pm, and 1 is Monday as Sunday is 0-indexed).

or every 15 minutes with

`*/15 * * * * /path/to/command`

And your command would be `~/scripts/myscript.sh` or whatever bash script has your sed command.

So you could have your cron job run schemer, then in the same script, put that string in your config file.  You'll probably need to reload your config file, and the command for that (to stick at the end of your script) is `source [path_to_config]`

And there you go.  Run schemer regularly, grab the string, stick it in your config file, and reload the file.  `cron`, some basic bash (as I am unfamiliar with schemer, or the nature of it's output beyond "it's a string"), `sed`, and `source`.

Sources for cron jobs, as I am less familiar with them than with sed:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: Thanks, great and elaborate answer! Could this work?
<code>
#!/bin/bash

#Todo; Find current wallpaper and set filename to $currentwallpaper

~/Go/bin/schemer -term="terminator" ~/Pictures/wallpapers/August2015/currentfilename > currentpalette #generate palette and redirect to temporary palette file

sed s/palette=/'echo currentpalette/g ~/.config/terminator/config #insert generated palette into terminator config

rm currentpalette #remove temporary palette file
</code>

Comment: If the `echo` does work, your sed command replaces "palette=" with the result of the echo call.

Remember, `sed s/first_string/second_string/g` will replace all instances of the first string in a give text file with the second string -- **not** stick them after it or append it in any way.

So you don't want to replace "palette=" in your config file.  You want to replace some placeholder string you have after it -- going from "palette=firststring" to "palette=otherphrase" requires `sed s/firststring/otherphrase/g`.  Notice how the `sed` command doesn't have the phrase 'palette=' in it.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that yesterday and it was correct but lacked some wildcards to make sed replace the whole line in the config-file. I've gotten it to work now under Cinnamon 2.6.13 which has horrible management of wallpapers as I've found. I'll post the complete code as an answer to my question. Thanks for all your help Xenophon.

Answer (score 1):

Running Cinnamon 2.6.13 on Arch Linux, I wrote this code that, from a directory defined, takes a random file and applies it as the wallpaper. Afterwards it runs schemer and copies the newly generated config into Terminators config directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Todo; 
currentmonth=August2015 
#directory of wallpaper
currentfilename="$(ls ~/Pictures/wallpapers/"$currentmonth" | shuf -n 1)"
#set $currentfilename to random filename from $currentmonth
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/cogitantium/Pictures/wallpapers/"$currentmonth"/"$currentfilename" 
#set wallpaper as current filename from default directory.
~/Go/bin/schemer -term="terminator" ~/Pictures/wallpapers/"$currentmonth"/"$currentfilename" > ~/Scripts/temp/currentpalette 
#generate palette and redirect output to temporary palette file
echo "$currentmonth - $currentfilename - $currentpalette"
currentpalette="$(cat temp/currentpalette)"
#set $currentpalette to currentpalette
touch "temp/config"
sed -i "s/^.*\bpalette\b.*$/$currentpalette/g" "temp/config"
#insert generated palette into terminator config
cp "temp/config" "~/.config/terminator/config"
```

It does contain some errors and behaves irregularly at times. Furthermore, Terminator doesn't seem to react to the changes, even after a killall. I'll update my answer, should I find a solution.